# Creating variable in kineticjs

Tags: javascript, image, kineticjs

In [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gkefk/51/), after dropping image into container every image is stored in the variable called image.but I want to store each dropped image to be stored in different variables name.It's not working(image1.onload).how can I do this?

```
   if($(ui.helper).hasClass("sticky")){
            console.log();
             var image = new Kinetic.Image({
                name: data,
                id: "image"+(imageCount++),
                x: $stageContainer.width() / 2 - ($(ui.helper).width() / 2),
                y: $stageContainer.height() / 2 - ($(ui.helper).height() / 2),
                image: theImage,
                draggable: false
            });
        }else{

            var image1 = new Kinetic.Image({
                name: data,
                id: "image"+(imageCount++),
                x: x,
                y: $stageContainer.height() / 2 - ($(ui.helper).height() / 2),
                image: theImage,
                draggable: true
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think using an array might be the way to go.

```
var images = [];

images.push(new Kinetic.Image({
    name: data,
    id: "image"+(imageCount++),
    x: x,
    y: $stageContainer.height() / 2 - ($(ui.helper).height() / 2),
    image: theImage,
    draggable: true
}))
```

You can reference them with their index in the array then like `images[0].onload`

Comment: still i couln't solve this problem.can you give full answer? @ZachWolf

Comment: Yeah, can you give me a little more detail on what you're looking to do? Is there only one image, but which image is loaded depends on some conditions? Or are you wanting to listen to a variable amount of image events.

Comment: In that fiddle, within drag drop method, every created image is stored in a one variable called "Image". because I want to add mouse event to a particular image.if i do image.on('dragmove') method for every image it will applied. how can I do??? @ZachWolf

Comment: Ok, I think I get what you mean. In the `dragDrop` function, `var image` refers to the image just placed on the stage. If you wanted to be able to manipulate all the images on the stage at once, you'd have to bind events to each image and store an array of all images. Then when an event is fired on a single image, manipulate the whole collection. Here's a basic example of how that could work with new code at the bottom. http://jsfiddle.net/98t0xq7k/1/